# Centering RAIL GALLERY with paddings on top and bottom

Tags: html, css

I just downloaded a theme and I'm trying to edit it a little bit.

So, I have gallery content with images at 100% height which I edited in functions.php `add_image_size( 'gallery-scroll', 900, 1500, false );` to max-height 1500px and max-width 900px.

I need to center them, like adding to image div height 100% of window and then add to this parent div padding of 120px. Like if it is a 24' screen, it will automatically resize the picture to window height with larger dimensions. Similarly, if a laptop is 15', it will resize to a smaller size. I don't know what code to give you guys but here is what I have:

```
 <div class="container">    
     <div class="main gallery">
         <div id="frame" style="overflow: hidden;">
             <ul class="image-gallery slidee thumbnails-6" style="transform: translateZ(0px); width: 5400px;">
                 <li class="fade active" data-url-id="767">
                     <a href="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DSC07944for-print-21x15-850x1270.jpg" class="thumb full_image" title="SONY DSC" ind="0">
                         <img width="900" height="1345" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DSC07944for-print-21x15-900x1345.jpg" class="attachment-gallery-scroll" alt="" ind="0">
                     </a>
                 </li>
```

**this was html** and now **css**

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main.gallery {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}

#frame {
    height: 100%;
}

ul.image-gallery.slidee {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to put the image into the centre of the screen(horizontally and vertically) independent of the screen size? Did not understand the question completely.

Comment: No, I have gallery rail like all pictures are movning into left and right like scrolling gallery but on buttons. Im trying to resize my pictures which are 1400px to the height of the window size and then give to this gallery block paddings on bottom and top ^^ open the website 2 youl understand it quickly^^ thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can center them using few different methods like-
1.) Use absolute positioning, example-

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
  margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
 }
```

2.)Or you could use align property on your li, example-

```
.image-gallery {
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}

.image-gallery li {
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Also to change the image size with every screen size-
1.) Give image height in %ages  rather than pixels.
2.) Use a series of @media queries to set the width and height to different values based on the current screen size.

Comment: Thansk bro but i inserted thiss css in this 2 variantions and its not working for me. Did you inspected website 1  with this css and it was like on website example 2?^^ THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear to me  , but from what I understand ,you need to place the the image in the centre of the screen independent of the screen size.

for that set the following css to the image container

```
.imagecontainer
{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

`margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` or simply `margin:auto` will set the element to the centre of the page. That is equal margin on both sides of the element( if the element is smaller than the parent element).

`verical-align:middle` as the the name itself suggests will align the division into the middle.

Comment: Sorry , I don't know English well so. I want to make gallery on my website similar to gallery which is using website 2(add max height to images  100% of screen and add to this block paddings on top and bottom as on the second website in the question)